# EC2 in unhealthy status with ALB and ASG

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I built two EC2 servers that are attached to an ASG and both servers are also attached to an ALB. One servers is in eu-west-2a and the other is in eu-west-2b.

The servers are constantly terminating and new ones are created and I can't figure out why. They are new servers.

```
The setup is

# Target group for ALB which is set up in the above code under target_group
resource "aws_lb_target_group" "targetgroup" {
  name     = "targetgroup"
  target_type = "instance"
  port     = 80
  protocol = "HTTP"
  vpc_id   = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id

 health_check {
  path                = "/"
  port                = 80
  protocol            = "HTTP"
  healthy_threshold   = 10
  unhealthy_threshold = 10
  matcher             = "200-499"
  }
```

port80 is open in the security group.

**ASG Activity Error**

One of the errors in ASG Activity is:
Terminating EC2 instance: i-04dbb4d0f8c06b355 - Waiting For ELB Connection Draining.    At 2024-03-11T15:02:16Z an instance was taken out of service in response to an EC2 health check indicating it has been terminated or stopped.

The more common error I see in the activity list is:
Launching a new EC2 instance: i-0d4840406c9612b45. Status Reason: Instance became unhealthy while waiting for instance to be in InService state. Termination Reason: Client.InstanceInitiatedShutdown: Instance initiated shutdown

The ASG setup:

```
# Auto scaling group build
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "my_asg" {
  name                      = "my_asg"
  max_size                  = 1
  min_size                  = 1
  health_check_type         = "ELB"    # optional
  desired_capacity          = 1
  target_group_arns = [aws_lb_target_group.targetgroup.arn]
  health_check_grace_period  = 300 
  vpc_zone_identifier       = [aws_subnet.public-subnet-1.id, aws_subnet.public-subnet-2.id]
```

Scale up and scale down policy

```
# scale up policy for ASG
resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "scale_up" {
  name                   = "scale_up"
  policy_type            = "SimpleScaling"
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.my_asg.name
  adjustment_type        = "ChangeInCapacity"
  scaling_adjustment     = "1"      # add one instance
  cooldown               = "300"    # cooldown period after scaling
}

# scale down policy for ASG

resource "aws_autoscaling_policy" "scale_down" {
  name                   = "asg-scale-down"
  autoscaling_group_name = aws_autoscaling_group.my_asg.name
  adjustment_type        = "ChangeInCapacity"
  scaling_adjustment     = "-1"
  cooldown               = "300"
  policy_type            = "SimpleScaling"
}
```

Comment: Your EC2 instance is not responding with `200 OK` HTTP status codes when the load balancer performs health checks (HTTP `GET` requests) against the `/` path. Do you actually have some sort of web server software installed and running on those EC2 servers, and listening on port `80`?

Comment: I have nothing installed on the servers, they're brand new builds. I have port 80 open, though. 

What should I change the / to?

Comment: Since you have defined http health via port 80 it expects the httpstatus code 200 in response to mark it healthy.

Comment: when you run your code define a open health check endpoint ( without any authentication). And when the ELB will try to check that endpoint will return 200 marking your instance healthy

Comment: Silly question but how would I add code to define the health check? I'm starting to think I built the wrong LB. Should I have built a NLB instead of an ALB?

Comment: It depends on how you want your ELB to decide if the instance is healthy.  If you are using NLB, you can use tcp and once your ELB establish a tcp connection successfully it says its healthy. same way http or https for ALB. I dont have any info on what purpose you are using the instance, but ultimately it will run some kind of code/software, so defining healthcheck on 80 could be a way. thanks!

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. So if it runs code, I will need to add a healthcheck at the beginning of the code on port 80?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using an ALB, it is expected that the targets are running with a Web Application. As your Health Check configuration is using **HTTP:80**, you should have something listening on this port on the instance and give an HTTP response in the range of **200-499** as you have mentioned. Usually User-data is used to perform this action and is mentioned in the **Launch Template** that you are using.

Giving a sample user-data to install httpd and make a dummy file available at root path as an example: [You can create a new Template of version including the user-data under **Advanced details > User data**]

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install -y httpd
systemctl start httpd
systemctl enable httpd
usermod -a -G apache ec2-user
chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
chmod 2775 /var/www
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2775 {} \;
find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0664 {} \;
cd /var/www/html
echo "<html><body><p><b>Test Success</b></p></body></html>" >> index.html
```

I am taking an assumption that your instances are having access to internet to update and install the httpd package to proceed.

Comment: That resolved the issue and the instances are now stable and not scaling up and down.

Thank you so much!